# Error: Cannot change background color of button

Tags: ios, string, swift, uicolor, sender

When I click a button I have a panel of buttons that pops up that has the name of a color on the button. When I click that color the code below should change two of my buttons to the color chosen, but right now I select it, it prints the sender.currentTitle's color like `Optional("Red")`.

Except when I click the button, the color of the button doesn't change. In fact, when I hit "Red" the print function in the red area below I called isn't printing so that function isn't being called.

My code for when I click one of the colors:

```
@IBAction func button1ActualColorChosen(sender: AnyObject) {
    var coliString1 = "\(sender.currentTitle!)"
    print("\(coliString1)")
    if coliString1 == "Black"{
    Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Red"{
        print("red")
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Green"{
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Orange"{
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Blue"{
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Cyan"{
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Brown"{
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Gray"{
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Purple"{
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    }
    if coliString1 == "Magenta"{
        Button1C.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
        button1Bang.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
    }
    Button1C.alpha = 1
}
```

As you can see I put the colors separate cause Idk how to not do that. How can I call the functions that say `if coliString1 == "Red"{}"` etc.

Comment: So you are setting coliString1 to "\(sender.currentTitle!)", then you are checking if it is "Red", "Black", or whatever. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure about Switf and iOS, but I know it's C-family, right? You should check online for 1) a string comparator method, and 2) the reason it's better to compare strings with a method rather than operands(==, !=, etc). Hope that helped. I'd hate to provide a very short answer and get blasted by the community. Good luck :). P.S., Java uses the method `.equals("");` to compare strings. Just a hint on what to look for.

Comment: @PhilC. I appreciate the concern, and that's generally a good point, but actually `==` is correct in Swift.

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  You've unwrapped the value of `sender.currentTitle`, so when you print that out it should be "Red", not "Optional("Red")".  Try directly printing `print(sender.currentTitle!)`, and post what comes out

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one issue with the line

```
var coliString1 = "\(sender.currentTitle!)"
```

Since sender.currentTitle! returns a string you dont need to use string interpolation to assign it to the variable coliString1. Also using a switch statement could help clean things up a bit.

```
@IBAction func button1ActualColorChosen(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let coliString1 = button.currentTitle

    var newColor = UIColor()

    if let cs1 = coliString {
        switch cs1 {
            case "Black":
                newColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            case "Red":
                newColor = UIColor.redColor()
            case "Green":
                newColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            case "Orange":
                newColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            case "Blue":
                newColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            case "Cyan":
                newColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
            case "Brown":
                newColor = UIColor.brownColor()
            case "Gray":
                newColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            case "Purple":
                newColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
            case "Magenta":
                newColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
            default:
                newColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
     }

     Button1C.backgroundColor = newColor
     button1Bang.backgroundColor = newColor

     Button1C.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to take this into consideration!